# Замена значений в MySQL

Tags: mysql

У меня есть в базе данных много записей с значением "ИсторияКазахстана", как мне быстро поменять их значение на "История Казхастана". Через какой метод или что-то...

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table` SET `row`='История Казахстана' WHERE `row`='ИсторияКазахстана'
```

Comment: Делаю аналогичный запрос, PHPmyadmin выдаёт сообщение: #1146 - Table 'username_tm.table' doesn't exist

Comment: 'username_tm.table' а у вас таблица действительно называется 'table'?